# Input data for network metanalysis using correlation coefficients.

Tags: network-meta-analysis

1) Can you perform network meta-analysis with correlation coefficients?

2) if so, would the contrasts (for the r package netmeta) be the difference between one correlation and the other (simple subtraction)?

3) Do the correlation coefficients need to be fisher z transformed first?

4) should I use the standard error of the difference of two correlation coefficients for the SE input for the netmeta r package?

Comment: I am not sure I follow you, but if you use mvmeta then you could simply put for each correlation coefficient the point estimate and the variance, without any further ado

Comment: Based on your answer it sounds like mvmeta does network analysis. Do you know what formula they use to calculate the SE of the difference of two correlations? I'm using sqrt((1/(n1-3)) + (1/n2-3))) when I create the contrasts in netmeta but I'm not sure this is correct.